# How can find I out how much memory of the heap my android 2.3 app is using?

Tags: java, android, heap-memory

I made a java app for android 2.3.4 and would like to find out how much memory of the available heap it is using.

Reason for that is that the dalvik vm has a heap size limit and on my current device that limit is 32mb but I would also want to run it on devices with a heap size of only 16mb and need to find out if I have to make memory optimizations.

How can I find out how much of the current heap size is being used?

---

Edit: I did find (with the help of the answer) some useful pointers here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android

Comment: Thats not really a "duplicate" because I want to find out how much memory of the heap is being counted against the heap limit in the dalvik vm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DDMS supports tracking the heap size. Have a look [here under "Viewing heap usage for a process"](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html)